# Header not showing after i set magento to production

Tags: magento2

hey guys so i set my magento website to production finally using the command **bin/magento deploy:mode:set production** but now my custom header i made is not showing up
https://softncozy.com
did i miss something?

problem 2: many features does not work if i set ***Use Web Server Rewrites*** to YES 
so this has been bugging me for a while

Comment: did you do upgrade / deploy?

Comment: @SavanPatel yes i did **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_CA**

Answer (score 0):

Please check with cntrl+U. getting below error

> br /> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create
> directory
> /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/.
> Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy generation error:
> The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
> directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the
> 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
> directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
> generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
> signature of the related construct method, only. in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135 Stack
> trace:
>
> ## 0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35):
>
> Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...')
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/Class in **/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php** on
>
> line **135**

Comment: i dont get it ? cntrl+U where?

Comment: i am getting this error in chrome but now it's gone.

Comment: so do you have a solution?